# How do I execute string python will be input by the users via web application

Tags: python, exec, eval

We have a webApplication(.net) and calcuationengine (Python)

1. WebApplication: to show results  and Python Formula to users/and  write python Input Formulas
2. calcuationengine  : Calculate Formulas

The target solution is :Web application send a json file with code to be evaluated (or executed).

Can you give a option about Exec/eval

exemple formula

```
def calcul_Inf_monthly_rates(Input) :    
    try :
        output=np.array([(1+v)**(1/12)-1 for v in Input])
    except:
        logging.error("Inf_monthly_rates : Error Calcul")
        output=[]
    finally:
        return output
```

Comment: So the Web Application will send Python code in json and you want the Python program to execute it? Can we see a sample json file?

Comment: You want the user to be able to enter a line of python code, which you will then execute on your server? See any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your json looks like:

```
json_func = """{"func": len}"""
# I used a simple len function for example
```

You can use evel in the following way:

```
executed_func = eval(json_func)["func"]
# now you can run executed_func with params

print(executed_func("Hello")) # will output: 5
```

Comment: Checking the code is a very difficult task and it wasn't part of your original question. You have to think again about the design of your system in order to avoid security breaches.

Comment: One way is to encapsulate the functionalities into already made functions and let the user choose one of them.

Comment: exactly, I asked to think about the design, the solution,it to share a github with users .